# How do I use Dojo Toolkit in an Electron application?

Tags: dojo, electron

I'm exploring Electron and I've run into a roadblock. I can't figure out how to load the [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) and use it in Electron.

For example, here is the simple "Hello World" for Dojo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
        data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
    <script>
        require([
            'dojo/dom',
            'dojo/dom-construct'
        ], function (dom, domConstruct) {
            var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
            domConstruct.place('<em> Dojo!</em>', greetingNode);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

That works fine in a browser, but doesn't work at all in Electron. After a couple hours of googling and trying 50 different experiments I've gotten nowhere.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can disable `node-integration` as Shwany said, I believe that will effectively render the `ipc` modules useless, which will probably pose undesirable limitations since you won't be able to communicate between the main and renderer processes.

However, it is possible, with a bit of finagling, to get Dojo to play nice with Electron.  There are only a couple of things you need to do in your entry page.

Firstly, force the `host-node` has feature to `false`.  This can be done by setting it in `dojoConfig.has`, e.g.:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    has: {
        'host-node': false
    }
}
```

Secondly, as Shwany pointed out, Dojo is going to see the already-existing `require`, so we need to move that out before loading Dojo:

```
// Move Electron's require out before loading Dojo
window.electronRequire = require;
delete window.require;
```

After loading dojo.js, you can move Dojo's require elsewhere and move Electron's back, if you wish.  Whether you want to do this may depend on how you intend to code the client side of your application.  Ostensibly, Dojo's global `require` is never needed, since you can request a context-sensitive `require` in any defined module via the `'require'` module ID.

If you want to see a scaffolded Electron application incorporating Dojo, I created a [boilerplate](https://github.com/kfranqueiro/electron-dojo-boilerplate) a few weeks ago (though be advised it's currently relying on a fork of electron-packager).  If you want to see an example of a more full-blown Electron/Dojo application, I wrote a music player called [Nukebox](https://github.com/kfranqueiro/nukebox) a couple of months ago which uses Dojo and dgrid (though its scaffolding is a bit different than the newer boilerplate).

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer. That will definitely work.

Comment: this is so great. I can use it to have a hybrid web and desktop application by checking for "electron" before performing that swap, and then I can still use the electronRequire inside the app such as using electronRequire('fs') to access filesystem functions...

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked great for me too. In my case forcing the `host-node` to `false` was enough for running the app before compiling the build, and to be able to run the compiled build, I needed to move out the electron's require as indicated.

Answer (score 2):

I have your test code working in Electron.

First, I assume you are trying to load dojo.js from the web. //ajax.googleapis... etc will probably attempt to pull the file from the file system. I added `http:` to the front of it. That allowed me to open a .html file in the browser and work. I am not sure if that was an oversight or not.

Secondly, because the browser-window has node-integration on by default, 'require' is already defined and it does not understand what you are passing to it because it expects a path not an array. If you construct your browser window with node-integration turned off it should work:

```
  app.on('ready', function() {  
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, "node-integration": false});  
  mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
  mainWindow.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });  
});
```

Note the `"node-integration": false`. This may cause additional issues if you want to use node integrations in your app. However, your code should work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to get it to *partially* work using your suggestion, but in fact I do need node integration. Ken's solution below is more workable for me.

Comment: Yes, that is a better solution building on what I noted here :)